# Git Unable to access jarfile /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.3/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.3.jar

Tags: git, devops

I'm not able to push anything up to DevOps using GIT.

Does anyone know how to change the jarfile path on Mac?  I have git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar so that is why I keep seeing this error.

Comment: Git itself does not care about jar (java archive) files. *Java* cares about them, so you should probably poke at this from the Java end of things.

Comment: The credentials manager is configured within git config. If this jar path is not correct you can fix it in your `~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 0):

It is correct what Ziarn pointed out above. The setting that is causing this error, is found inside your ~/.gitconfig file. (Linux / Mac). Windows users can find it here: C:\ProgramData\Git\config

I have had the same problem and needed to update the path to my OpenJDK (new version had a different path).

Once the path was fixed, the error disappeared and my Git credentials worked again.